# How might wizards figure out how to walk on the moon?

Tags: science-based, space-travel, moons

A group of wizards is currently planning a trip to the moon to study why it makes werewolves happen. They plan to teleport to the lunar surface, do a few hours of investigation (e.g. watch samples of werewolf blood through a microscope, or hit moon rocks with enchanted chisels), and return to Earth.

What sorts of issues will they encounter, and how might they discover that they exist in order to plan around them?

Details:

- Global knowledge of the moon and space is somwhere near our world in the 1850s-1900s (i.e. not much). Technology's about the same, but the wizards would prefer to use their own wits and spells where possible.
- The wizards already suspect one issue: the moon's climate is probably like a very high mountain. Therefore, they plan to wear very warm clothing and use a spell to wear an air bubble around their heads (like a fishbowl helmet with infinite resupply).
- The wizards can write new spells to do pretty much anything, but they need to have an idea what the spell needs to do; they can't just go "make it safe to walk on the moon" and have it happen.
- Teleportation can only be initiated at the departure side, so they cannot retrieve any "probes" they send without someone going there themselves. (This is open to change if necessary.)
- Multiple trips are expected.

Some issues I think might arise would be:

- Is the moon's surface too hot/cold to touch without special gloves/boots? (Both day and night trips are planned.)
- What'll the radiation do? Air's a buffer but how big a bubble would they need? Is the idea of radiation poisoning even comprehendable in this time period?

Anything else?

Comment: The [help/dont-ask] states, "To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where … your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers."  This looks an awful lot like you've answered your own question and you want more answers.  VTC OT:NAW until you ask a specific question.  Remember, [SE is not a discussion forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums/92110#92110).

Comment: @JBH: To be pedantic, would the question have been okay if I had simply omitted that I already suspected a few answers?

Comment: Yes, you need to do that.  No, it's likely not enough.  By simply removing your insight, you leave your question asking for an off-topic [infinite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6139/40609). We need to convert it to an on-topic [finite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6138/40609).  As you [edit] your question to remove your answers, think about what, exactly, a best answer would do for you.  Are you looking for general ratification of your idea? (read about the [tag:reality-check] tag.) Is there a specific weakness to address? Etc.

Comment: Guess I'll just let it die then, since it's not letting me delete it.

Comment: Ah.  Don't delete the question, [edit] it.  Once you've edited the question, it's automatically submitted to the Vote to Reopen (VTR) queue.  If the edits clarify the question appropriately (aka, if you get five thumbs up), the question is reopened.  SE's close-and-reopen system is specifically designed to help new users learn how each stack deals with questions.  We want them to be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

The moon's surface gets very hot during the day - up to 100 degrees C, water's boiling point - and very cold during the night - -173 degrees C, far colder than any natural environment on Earth. The good news is that as long as they are protected from actually touching the surface, they could survive for quite a bit longer than you'd expect in these temperatures, since vacuum is the best insulator there is. The temperature will kill them eventually, but it will take a while and can probably be handled with magic.

A more urgent problem would be depressurization. While not as dramatic as movies often make it appear (you won't explode) it will make gases in your blood begin to bubble, which is painful and deadly, and your tissues will start to swell, causing a host of problems. However, if the wizards are smart this might not be entirely unexpected. On Earth, a similar phenomenon happens when people come to the surface after deep-sea diving, called the bends. If the wizards have explored the depths of the ocean, they probably have a spell to prevent the bends. They can apply the same principles to protect them in space.

At least one types of radiation is probably comprehensible - a person exposed to space will receive an intense sunburn almost immediately from the unfiltered solar radiation. They might predict this if they have been on high mountains. However, space is also filled with nastier rays that people rarely encounter on Earth, unless they have been exposed to radioactive materials. Radiation was *just* being discovered at the end of the 19th century, though its dangers were not known until later (when scientists who worked with radiation started dying of cancer.) If your wizards have been studying radiation and have something approximating a Geiger counter, they may recognize that space has far more of these rays than the unrefined materials they have been studying. Whether they realize it is something they have to protect themselves from is another question. Our scientists certainly didn't.

Comment: Exposure to vacuum and decompression sickness are _wildly_ different things. Protection from one will likely not help you with the other in slightest.

Answer (score 2):

## They do it in steps.

Very little is known about the Moon, so they need probing. The probing will consist in a small group of the most powerful mages available, wrapped in all sorts of protective spells, that will teleport to the Moon and back for longer and longer times - initially they will stay there for as little as they can, maybe less than one second. They will also bring with them a lot of equipment:

- living organisms of various kinds (from Petri dishes to small mammals)
- "snap-trap" sample bottles, filled with hard vacuum, that will automatically open on the Moon to capture its atmosphere and hold it in airtight, spell-reinforced containers for analysis
- temperature and irradiation recorders, photographic plate spells and so on
- electroscopes

After a half dozen round-trips they establish that the Moon is an airless desert, with temperatures from above the boiling point of water to below the freezing point of carbon dioxide.

So, the next mage squads are equipped with simpler and simpler cantrips:
 - vacuum protection
 - oxygen/CO2 regulation
 - temperature regulation
 - solar rays screen

After a short while they'll discover radiations and solar wind, but the lowered gravity was discovered immediately with all mages reporting a "falling" sensation.

The solution is one they have long possessed - artificial gravity, a blending of two spells, one that suppresses gravity, the other imparting a constant acceleration in a direction of one's choosing, thus allowing walking sideways on buildings or performing difficult maintenance in awkward places (it is also disqualified from several sports and despised by mountaineers, but that's another story).

Answer (score 1):

### Observation

If they are as witty and knowledgeable as you imply, they make some educated guesses without risking their own neck. You won't become an old wizard by blindly trying to manipulate the elements. You will be a textbook case.

Observations derived from deep in the oceans: Air bubble may be crushed, with wizard body included without proper pressure management.

Simply observing the sun: Complete insulation of heat exchange over the whole body. If they can cast any spell and probably fought each other at some point, this kind of defense magic should be a given.

### Experiments

Even if they can't initiate teleporting back without going themselves, why would they go to an unknown, possibly extremely hazardous (no life observed) place personally at first. Send plants, little animals or if they are evil, slaves. Apply their theorized defense magic on the subjects. Observe from the safety of Earth (by magic) or apply monitoring magic, which sends back data on the condition of the test subjects. A simply alive or dead is good enough.
I'm sure as hell wouldn't teleport over if a plant didn't survive for minutes or even days without problem.

### Just like humanity did, gradual steps